# `cat` affects last `Access` time but not last `Change` time

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, timestamps, file-metadata

On my Ubuntu system, I've created a new file `prueba.txt` using `touch prueba.txt`. When I show its file statistics using `stat prueba.txt`, the output is as follows:

```
  File: prueba.txt
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fc01h/64513d    Inode: 4092        Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2022-10-07 13:04:57.621272608 +0000
Modify: 2022-10-07 13:04:57.621272608 +0000
Change: 2022-10-07 13:04:57.621272608 +0000
 Birth: 2022-10-07 13:04:57.621272608 +0000
```

Then, when I print the contents of the file using `cat prueba.txt` and then run `stat prueba.txt` again, the ouput is as follows:

```
  File: prueba.txt
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fc01h/64513d    Inode: 4092        Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2022-10-07 13:06:18.852005488 +0000
Modify: 2022-10-07 13:04:57.621272608 +0000
Change: 2022-10-07 13:04:57.621272608 +0000
 Birth: 2022-10-07 13:04:57.621272608 +0000
```

Note that the `Access` time has changed, but the `Change` time has not. However, in the `man 7 inode` entry that describes (among other things) this file metadata, the following information is provided about the meaning of `Change`:

```
Last status change timestamp (ctime)
              stat.st_ctime; statx.stx_ctime

              This is the file's last status change timestamp.  It is changed by writing or by setting inode informa‐
              tion (i.e., owner, group, link count, mode, etc.).
```

If I understand correctly, the `Change` time should be updated whenever any file data *or metadata* is modified, including (I assume) the `Access` metadata. So how is it that `cat`ing the file affects the value of its `Access` metadata, but does not alter its `Change` metadata in the process? Am I misunderstanding the meaning of this `man` entry, or misunderstanding how `cat` works in some way?

Comment: `(i.e., owner, group, link count, mode, etc.)`  If __accessing__ a file modified it's last __changed__ timestamp that would be a bug.

Comment: @jesse_b Is "last accessed" data not part of the inode information?

Comment: It doesn't say changing any inode information and it also says "setting inode information"  When the last access time is updated _you_ are not setting it, the system is.  Again, if it behaved the way you expect it to it would be a bug and would completely negate the purpose of access vs change.

Answer (score 1):

Linux keeps three timestamps for each file:

- **mtime**: Time of last modification to file contents (data itself). Can be seen via `ls -l`
- **ctime**: Time of last change to file contents or file metadata (owner, group, permissions, link count, etc.). This does not include timestamps. Can be seen via `ls -lc`
- **atime**: Time of last access to file for reading its contents. Can be seen via `ls -lu`

Reading a file via `cat` changes its atime, as expected. Neither file contents nor its metadata are changed during this operation, so its ctime is not modified.

Comment: These POSIX links can be handy to dismiss any doubt: [write](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html): "Upon successful completion, where nbyte is greater than 0, write() shall mark for update the last data modification and last file status change timestamps of the file" , vs [read](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html):  "Upon successful completion, where nbyte is greater than 0, read() shall mark for update the last data access timestamp of the file, and shall return the number of bytes read" : no ctime for read.